# string to file stream using php or jquery

Tags: php, jquery, filestream

i have image that was in `base64` format as follows:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkCAYAAABw4pVUAAAgAE........
```

I am trying to convert the above string to input file stream. I have checked for this but i didn't get anything, please let me know the process.

Comment: i mean i have searched for this but i am getting the results to convert string to file stream in java and c# only,thats why i posted here...

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `file put contents`.

Try this:

```
// Your image data

$data = data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkCAYAAABw4pV....

list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list(, $data) = explode(',', $data);

//Image name
$filename = "myname.png";

$data = base64_decode($data);

$file = 'uploads/' . $filename;

// decode the image data and save it to file
file_put_contents($file, $data);
```

Comment: i am doing this in my side,but i need to post that image to .net server so i need to post image like browse file (i mean after browsing the it will convert into stream and then we post the file using post method),so i need this file in stream format...so that i can easily post the file using post method

Comment: @shivakakileti I didn't understand clearly,you want a save dialog box to save that image file in a selected folder???

Comment: thanks for reply,actually i want to post that image (in base64 format) to aspx page,i mean the image saving functionality is doing on aspx page ,but file sending(by posting)through php code,they will catch the file like($_FILES['filename']) like ,so inorder to get the i need to send the image like input stream

Comment: is there any possibilty to convert base64 string to input stream in php

Comment: To decode base64 to string you can use this: `base64_decode($base64data)`